# Getting a "AttributeError at /case/57286/" in KIWI TCMS for some test cases when migrated from testopia

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have migrated test plans, cases from testopia environment to kiwi tcms. Most of the plans and cases are ok. But when viewing test cases in some test plans, getting  an error AttributeError at /case/57286/. what could be the reason for this?

following is the stack trace from the error..

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://*******:8000/plans/printable/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:

```
['vinaigrette',
 'grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'attachments',
 'django_comments',
 'modernrpc',
 'simple_history',
 'tcms.core',
 'tcms.kiwi_auth',
 'tcms.core.contrib.comments.apps.AppConfig',
 'tcms.core.contrib.linkreference',
 'tcms.management',
 'tcms.testcases.apps.AppConfig',
 'tcms.testplans.apps.AppConfig',
 'tcms.testruns.apps.AppConfig',
 'tcms.xmlrpc',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'tcms.core.middleware.CsrfDisableMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'global_login_required.GlobalLoginRequiredMiddleware',
 'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
 'tcms.core.middleware.CheckSettingsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Template error:
In template /hms/apps/Kiwi/tcms/templates/case/printable.html, error at line 57
   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
   47 :     <div>
   48 :         <h2 id="plan_cases">Test Cases</h2>
   49 :         <div class="thick-line"></div>
   50 :     {% for case_id, test_cases in test_cases.items %}
   51 :         <div style="clear: left">
   52 :             {% for test_case in test_cases %}
   53 :         <h3>TC-{{ test_case.case_id }}: {{ test_case.case__summary }}</h3>
   54 :         <div class="thin-line"></div>
   55 :         <div class="case-stage">
   56 :             <h4>Set up</h4>
   57 :              {{ test_case.setup|markdown2html }} 
   58 :         </div>
   59 :         <div class="case-stage">
   60 :             <h4>Actions</h4>
   61 :             {{ test_case.action|markdown2html }}
   62 :         </div>
   63 :         <div class="case-stage">
   64 :             <h4>Expected Results</h4>
   65 :             {{ test_case.effect|markdown2html }}
   66 :         </div>
   67 :         <div class="case-stage">


Traceback:

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  40.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/hms/apps/Kiwi/tcms/testplans/views.py" in printable
  650.     return testcases_printable(request)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  40.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/hms/apps/Kiwi/tcms/testcases/views.py" in printable
  882.     return render(request, template_name, context_data)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  96.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  698.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/hms/apps/Kiwi/tcms/core/templatetags/extra_filters.py" in markdown2html
  20.                                        extensions=['markdown.extensions.fenced_code']))

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/markdown/core.py" in markdown
  391.     return md.convert(text)

File "/home/centos/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/markdown/core.py" in convert
  252.         if not source.strip():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /plans/printable/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Thank You

Comment: Post the traceback as a comment here b/c I don't have access to these documents. Make sure you remove any confidential information you don't want to expose to the public.

Comment: hi, added the trace back to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your texts have the value of None instead of empty string and rendering fails. Try adding

`if md_str is None:
        md_str = ''`

As the first operation in `tcms/core/templatetags/extra_filters.py::markdown2html()` function and see if it solves the problem. If yes, we can include this patch in the next version of Kiwi TCMS.